# Radius of convergence of power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}$ Radius of convergence

I know Radius of convergence $(1/R)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ where $a_n$ is nth term of $\sum a_n |z-a|^n$

But here z is interms of powers of n!

nth term = 1; with z-power as $z^{n!}$ .

$a_n = 1, a_{n-1}=0 \implies 1/R = 1/0 = \infty \implies R=0$

If we take  $a_n = 0, a_{n-1}=1 \implies 1/R = 0/1 =0; \implies R= \infty$

Pls point me to where i am making mistake.

Comment: You have to take a look at the coefficients for general $n$, not for specific values. First try writing out what $a_k$ are, in terms of $z^k$, not $z^{n!}$.

Comment: There is a stronger result.. See Wikipedia [Lacunary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).

Comment: That formula for  $R$ is correct _if_ $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$ _exists. In this example that limit does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $z=1$, the series diverges. Therefore, $R\leqslant1$.

But if $|z|<1$, $|z|^{n!}\leqslant|z|^n$. So, by the comparison test, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$ converges absolutely.

So, $R=1$.

Comment: thank you Sir, very simple and lucid

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

The exact fomula is  *Hadamard's formula*:
$$\frac1 R=\limsup_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{\tfrac1n}$$