# Radius of convergence of complex power series $\sum_{k\geq0} z^{k!}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm struggling a bit with determining convergence radius for complex power series.

Determine radius of convergence for: $\sum_{k\geq0} z^{k!}$.

In previous in exercises I've done $lim_k\rightarrow \infty$  $\rvert ak \rvert^\frac{1}{k}$, but it look to me that $ak$ does not exist, which makes me wonder how to solve this.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/595501/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2813968/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%5Cgeq0%7D%20z%5E%7Bk!%7D%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Aradius)

Comment: A bit obvious that the series converges for $z\in [0,1)$ and diverges at $z=1$